# ASP.NET sitemap not displaying child nodes using asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, sitemap

The above is my ASP.NET code

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />                
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menuRepeater" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

and here is the sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Homepage">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Login.aspx" title="Login"/>
    <siteMapNode url="~/News.aspx" title="News"/>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Preferences.aspx" title="Preferences"/>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The problem with above code is that it only shows the parent node (~/Default.aspx), however when I use the Menu or TreeView control and specify the SiteMapDataSource, everything works properly. Can you please spot where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set ShowStartingNode="false"  in SiteMapDataSource markup.

Comment: Yes this is working but can you tell me what was the problem? I want all the nodes to be shown including the home one

Comment: The SiteMapDataSource control returns the site map hierarchy one level at a time, starting with the root site map node. By setting the ShowStartingNode=false it bypasses the Root node and starts with Home. I suggest you read http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-pages-and-site-navigation-cs

Answer (score 0):

Vijay's suggestion and comment link eventually provided the answer for me as well.

The summary version is **nested repeaters**, as well as the ShowStartingNode=false setting. For posterity's sake, code from the above link:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
             NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>
             <%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>

            <asp:Repeater runat="server"
                DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
                         NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>
                         <%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```